# Does the system remove persons from chat if they are inactive for a long time?

Tags: support, chat

If I am inactive in a chat room (which is in gallery mode), for a long period of time, will the system remove me from that room automatically after some period of time?

I looked [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=chat%20rooms%20people%20removal) but was not able to find the exact answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is: *you will stay idle in the room forever, as long as you have a browser tab open on the same chat site*.

However, this whole thing works with client side scripting, sending requests to the server every 10 minutes to let it know you're still there, and the server is checking for inactive users every 5 minutes. This means that if either side of the connection (client or server) is down for over 10 minutes or so, the server would think you left the room, hence removing you from the room users list.

To sum this up: the system does not explicitly remove you from a room as long as you're in it (i.e. have a tab open with at least one room on the same chat site) however connection problems are quite common so most likely you'll be removed after few days if you leave the computer turned on and go away.

Comment: Two additions: First, it doesn't necessarily have to be a browser tab with *that particular room*, as long as it's a room on the same chat site (since you can still monitor other rooms in the sidebar, even if you're not looking precisely at that room, we continue to consider you being "in" that room). Second, short connection blips shouldn't be an issue; the keep-alive time, if you will, is 10-15 minutes (to be precise it's 10 minutes, but we only check for inactive users every 5 minutes).

Comment: Thanks @balpha would you post a new, complete, answer? Or do you prefer me to edit those additions into my answer?

Comment: Go ahead, feel free to include any of that in the answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard As I mentioned about the Gallery mode, So should I again get approved from the room owner to chat again in that room ?

Comment: @Javageek no, it's not relevant. The explicit write access is permanent, until the room owner removes it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Got it !